# Are There Any Dremel Cutting Wheels That Actually Cut Steel?

Tags: electrical, hvac, repair, metal, drill-bit

Recently,I was using my prized, vintage Dremel Moto Tool (model no. 2) in an attempt to sever a 1/8” diameter steel screw.  I was using Dremel’s S-99 steel cutting wheel.  Thinking that the cutting wheel would be up to the task I was disappointed to see that it had little effect on the screw.  My question is:  Are there any cutting wheels that can fit a Dremel and can easily handle severing a steel screw?

Comment: What's an S-99  I couldn't find it in the dremel catalog

Comment: Jasen—thank’s for your question.  The S-99 is (was) one of the bits among a list of 36 bits of varying shapes and sizes that Dremel referred to as Dremel high-speed (HS) steel cutters.  That designation, “steel” only meant that the bits were all made of steel, but not meant to actually cut steel.  The S-99 was a 3/32” steel shank with a wheel-shaped head, with cutting teeth around the edge of the wheel.  These bits were part of Dremel’s early line of cutting bits (ca. 1940’s).  However, as I discovered, they WEREN’T designed to cut through steel.   Soon, I’ll learn how to post photos.

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, they have these little discs that come in tubes of like 30.  They're cheap.

Those, plus patience, work fantastically for me.

You have to be very, very sensitive to excessive pressure or any side-load, misalignment with the cut slot, ripples, vibration effects or anything irregular.  Disengage immediately when you start to see that.  If you persist, the disc will shatter, and you'll have to pause to load a new disc.

Since shattering of a 15,000 RPM disc is on the menu, wear safety glasses and other appropriate PPE.

Comment: Thank you ‘Harper…’ for your reply.  I actually have in my vintage Dremel box those very disks—but I have a question about them:  I always thought that those disks were for sanding/grinding tasks as, they are small wheels coated with a very fine medium (grit) more suited (I thought) for sanding/abrading/grinding.  I never thought they could be used to actually cut through steel (much less hardened steel.)  Are you saying that those little dark reddish brown disks will cut through bolts?

Comment: @Julian I have used those discs for years to cut through bolts and other metallic items. They are very effective but are prone to shattering if you are not careful. Don't apply a lot of pressure; let the speed of the wheel do the work.

Comment: @Julian yup, it's pretty much my go-to when I need to avoid risking mutilation of the bolted surface (which a 4" angle grinder would do all too eagerly at the slightest loss of control)... like I say the key is patience...

Comment: @Julian I'm very impressed that you can use them for sanding! As noted in several answers/comments they will accept almost zero side load, so if you're sanding with the flat of it instead of cutting with the edge, you have got an _incredibly_ light touch!

Comment: 15000 RPM that slow?

Answer (score 4):

What you want to use are cutting wheels or grinding disks similar to the ones shown below. They have always worked great for me. They wear down faster than the heavier ones but they're thinner so they cut faster. They do break a little easier than the heavier one too.

[image]